# SQLDF R: Counting unique values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I have a data frame with one column. There are 10 rows.

```
(4.0 * 3.0)
(4.0 * 3.0)
(2.0 * (1.0 * (1.0 * 6.0)))
(4.0 * (3.0 * 1.0))
(6.0 * 2.0)
(6.0 * 2.0)
(2.0 * 6.0)
(2.0 * 6.0)
(2.0 * 6.0)
(6.0 * 2.0)
```

I need to extract the unique values in the column and the number of times it occurs. Using sqldf package I was able to get the unique values. But not the count.

Query:

```
sqldf("SELECT V1, COUNT(DISTINCT V1) as DinctC from dataset GROUP BY V1")
```

Output:

```
                           V1 DinctC
1 (2.0 * (1.0 * (1.0 * 6.0)))      1
2                 (2.0 * 6.0)      1
3         (4.0 * (3.0 * 1.0))      1
4                 (4.0 * 3.0)      1
5                 (6.0 * 2.0)      1
```

What I want is:

```
                           V1 DinctC
1 (2.0 * (1.0 * (1.0 * 6.0)))      1
2                 (2.0 * 6.0)      3
3         (4.0 * (3.0 * 1.0))      1
4                 (4.0 * 3.0)      2
5                 (6.0 * 2.0)      3
```

**Edit**:
As Tim Biegeleisen pointed out "Distinct" is not a function therefore no need of the brackets. So updating **DISTINCT(V1) to DISTINCT V1**

Answer (score 5):

We do not need the distinct keyword as we are using the GROUP BY clause.

```
sqldf("SELECT V1, COUNT(V1) as DinctC from dataset GROUP BY V1")
```

Result:

```
                           V1 DinctC
1 (2.0 * (1.0 * (1.0 * 6.0)))      1
2                 (2.0 * 6.0)      3
3         (4.0 * (3.0 * 1.0))      1
4                 (4.0 * 3.0)      2
5                 (6.0 * 2.0)      3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, V1)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#                          V1     n
#                       <chr> <int>
#1 (2.0 * (1.0 * (1.0 * 6.0)))     1
#2                 (2.0 * 6.0)     3
#3         (4.0 * (3.0 * 1.0))     1
#4                 (4.0 * 3.0)     2
#5                 (6.0 * 2.0)     3
```

---

Or `table` from `base R`

```
table(df$V1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However I'm looking for a way to get the same result with sqldf. In case I didn't find I'm going to use this method.

Comment: @SriniShine  Thanks for the comments.  I guess you already got another solution with sqldf